# I'm trying to have 10 arrays of strings and print the even length string

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArrayString 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the strings");
        int a=0;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            String[]str=new String[i];
        }
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            if(*str*.length[i]%2==0)
                System.out.println(String.*str*[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**str cannot be resolved to a variable Java(33554515)
str cannot be resolved or is not a field Java(33554502)**

Comment: str is a local variable within that loop. Once the loop is finished, the varaible doesn't exist anymore

Comment: also: you only create one array, and overwrite the previous array(s) each iteration. You should re-think your logic

Comment: how do I make it's scope work in the entire program

Comment: Move out the declaration from the loop.

Comment: There are a couple of other issues: 1) you ask the user for input but don't read anything from the scanner, 2) `String.str[i]` isn't correct syntax as there's no "field" `str` on class `String`. 3) `length` is an array property, so it's not `str.length[i]` but rather `str.length` (unless you mean `str` to be a 2D array in which case you could also use `str[i].length`). Given all that you might want to grab a tutorial and work your way through it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArrayString 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the strings");
        int a=0;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            String[]str=new String[i]; // this only exists within the scope of this loop
        }
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if(*str*.length[i]%2==0)
                System.out.println(String.*str*[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

First change, declare the array out of the loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArrayString 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the strings");
        int a=0;
        String[] str = null;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            str=new String[i];
        }
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if(str.length[i]%2==0)
                System.out.println(String.*str*[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This will both compile and run, but you'll only have the last array, since you overwrite the existing one each time.

EDIT: I was only referring to the scope issues, since that's the error you listed. I'll improve the 'fixed' version below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArrayString 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the strings");
        int a=0;
        String[] str = new String[10];
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            str[i] = "" + i; // actually add a value               
        }
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if(i%2==0) // divide the index, not the value, since those are Strings and you're trying to access them wrong
                System.out.println(str[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

What you can do is create a List, or an array, that contains the arrays, and iterate over that.

Comment: "This will both compile and run" - Would `str.length[i]` compile though? Or `String.*str*[i]`/`String.str[i]`? :) Also note that the strings would still be `null`...

Comment: do you thing integer str.length[i] can reference array element?

Comment: you're right. I was only checking for the scope issues :)